# I am having a problem with a while-loop math problem

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I was given a math problem which has to be solved with a while-loop specifically. I tried too many ways to solve it but unfortunately they don't seem to work.

Here is the math problem itself:

> The group stage of the world cup is about to end and Pepi wants to know if his favorite team will qualify. It is known that the following rules apply - if a team has scored more goals in a match than it has received, then it wins and receives 3 points; if the number of goals scored and received is equal, the team gets 1 point; in case of losing, the number of points does not change. The team is finally ranked if the total number of goals scored from all matches played is greater than or equal to the number of goals received. Write a program that calculates whether the team has qualified.
>
> Two lines are read from the console:
>
> - Team name - text;
> - Matches played - an integer positive in the interval [1… 10];
>
> There are two new lines for each game played:
>
> - Goals scored - positive integer in the interval [1… 10000];
> - Goals received - an integer positive in the interval [1… 10000];
>
> Two lines are printed on the console:
>
> - If the team qualifies:
>     "{team name} has finished the group phase with {points} points."
>     "Goal difference: {goal difference}."
> - If the team did not qualify:
>     "{team name} has been eliminated from the group phase."
>     "Goal difference: {goal difference}."

```js
function solve(input) {

  let name = input.shift();
  let matches_played = Number(input.shift());
  let matches = 0;
  let points_winner = 0;
  let points_loser = 0;
  let goalDifference = 0;
  let total = 0;

  while (matches <= matches_played) {
    let first_team = Number(input.shift());
    let second_team = Number(input.shift());

    if (first_team > second_team) {
      points_winner = points_winner + 3;
    } else if (first_team === second_team) {
      points_winner = points_winner + 1;
    } else if (first_team < second_team) {
      points_winner = points_winner + 0;
    }

    goalDifference = first_team - second_team;
    total = total + goalDifference;

    matches++;
  }

  if (points_winner >= points_loser) {
    console.log(`${name} has finished the group phase with ${points_winner} points.`)
  } else {
    console.log(`${name} has been eliminated from the group phase.`)
    console.log(`Goal difference: ${goalDifference}`)
  }
}

solve(['Brazil', 3, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1])
```

With the input displayed, the expected output is:

```
Brazil has finished the group phase with 5 points.
Goal difference: 2.
```

Comment: The code never updates `points_loser`, so `points_winner` is always more than `0`.

Comment: @AndreNuechter I fixed all the formatting and changed the code to a stack snippet. Why did you undo all that?

Comment: @Barmar, a race condition. I didn't mean to.

Comment: @Barmar The math problem does not say how to calculate the second team's points? Or is it just me not getting it? :/

Comment: The math problem doesn't make sense to me. First it talks about points, but qualifying is just based on the number of goals, not the points.

Comment: You need to put the goal difference line outside of the if statement

Comment: Also, `<=` should just be `<`.

Comment: @leonsegal Do you mean outside of the while loop because it is outside of the if statement?

Comment: @VictoriaTodorova at the moment, it only prints the goal difference if the first team is eliminated, but it should always print no matter the outcome. It should therefore not be inside the if/else statement. It is currently (and correctly I think) outside of the while loop. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement at the end should be based on `total`, not `points_winner`. If `total` is at least `0`, the team qualified.

If the total is less than 0, convert it to a positive number when showing the amount that it came short by.

When showing the goal difference at the end, you need to use `total`. `goalDifference` just contains the difference from the last match.

The `while` condition should be `matches < matches_played`. If you use `<=`, it loops an extra time and gets `undefined` for those missing array elements, which causes you to get `NaN` when you add them to `total`.

```js
function solve(input) {

  let name = input.shift();
  let matches_played = Number(input.shift());
  let matches = 0;
  let points_winner = 0;
  let goalDifference = 0;
  let total = 0;

  while (matches < matches_played) {
    let first_team = Number(input.shift());
    let second_team = Number(input.shift());

    if (first_team > second_team) {
      points_winner = points_winner + 3;
    } else if (first_team === second_team) {
      points_winner = points_winner + 1;
    } else if (first_team < second_team) {
      points_winner = points_winner + 0;
    }

    goalDifference = first_team - second_team;
    total = total + goalDifference;

    matches++;
  }

  if (total >= 0) {
    console.log(`${name} has finished the group phase with ${points_winner} points.`)
    console.log(`Goal difference: ${total}`)
  } else {
    console.log(`${name} has been eliminated from the group phase.`)
    console.log(`Goal difference: ${-total}`)
  }
}

solve(['Brazil', 3, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1])
solve(['Spain', 3, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 3])
```

Comment: The log else will never run as points_winner will always be at least zero

Comment: The points are not used for qualifying, just the number of goals.

Comment: thank you so much! In some cases total (the goal difference) prints NaN. Do you know why this is happening

Comment: That's because you used `<=` in your `while` condition instead of `<`, so you're looping too many times and getting undefined elements from the array.

Comment: if there are no points added/lost for losing, you could remove the else if check `first_team < second_team`.

Comment: also, some of the naming could be changed eg `points_winner` => `points_gained` and `first_team` => `home_team_score', `second_team_score` => `opposition_team`

Comment: thank you, guys, so much for the help! I've got it now and changed the code. It makes perfect sense now that you explained all these things to me!

Comment: @leonsegal You're getting into [codereview.se] territory. I'm just trying to help him get it working, not beautiful.

Comment: @Barmar ah ok, didn't realise that's how it worked. Glad you helped them.